# add dot line to all table cell in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have table in word. which each cell represent an hour I want to add six vertical light dot line to each cell in the table.
I use split cells and change the border style for inside cells but there is a limitation on the number of cells in a table. how can I draw this line?
the final result is like this:

[image]

Update:
I just want to print this table. so if there is another way? like use excel or other apps I will be happy to use them.

Update:
thanks for helping I use excel and the result is like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dwVp.png)

Comment: You could put a drawing with the lines behind the table. However, it would not be dynamic.

Comment: Excel might be a better application of the table. Is there a reason it has to be in Word?

Comment: NO. I just want to print the table.@Rich Michaels

Comment: "but there is a limitation on the number of cells in a table" - what is that limitation?

Comment: The limit for a table in Microsoft Word is 63 columns and that is why I recommend Excel, limit is over 16K, for this task.

Comment: thanks, I used excel and create my table like that I wanted @Rich Michaels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is the application to use for this task and not Word. Word's table column limit is 63 whereas Excel's is over 16K.

Comment: You should have said it's over 8000, which would still be correct. 